# number of ways of crossing river

Tags: combinatorics

A person has to cross a river, there are 5 stones in a line, he can make a single hop, i.e stone to stone or he can make a double hop, skipping one stone, now how many number of ways can he do it.

Comment: This question is asked in amazon's campus recruitment drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He needs to take six steps, one or two at a time. The possibilities are:

$$ 2 + 2 + 2 = 6 \quad \text{(one possibility)}$$

$$ 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 6 \quad \text{(six possibilities, depending on the order)}$$

$$ 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1= 6 \quad \text{(five possibilities, depending on the order)}$$

$$ 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6 \quad \text{(one possibility)}$$

So there are 13 ways in all.